# Is there a better way to get a value from one object in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

I'm developing an app with Vue 3, Vuetify 3, and Pinia. Assuming the user chooses a school year (for example "2023-2024") from a `<v-select>` on my form, I want to return a list of bus routes that are being operated during that school year into another `<v-select>` on the same form. I've put the school years and bus routes in a Pinia store that looks like this:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useRouteStore = defineStore('routeStore', {
    state: () => ({
        routes: [
            {schoolyear: "2022-2023", routeList: ["L-K311", "L-K312", "L-K325", "L-K326", "L-K336"]},
            {schoolyear: "2023-2024", routeList: ["C-K311", "C-K312", "C-K325", "C-K326", "C-K336"]},
            {schoolyear: "2024-2025", routeList: ["N-K311", "N-K312", "N-K325", "N-K326", "N-K336"]},
        ]
    })
})
```

I am able to get a routeList for a given year into my  as follows:

```
<v-select :items="getList('2023-2024')"></v-select>
```

using the following in my `<script>`:

```
<script setup>
import { useRouteStore } from '@/stores/RouteStore'

const routeStore = useRouteStore()

function getList(selectedSchoolyear) {
    
    let result = new Array();
    let oneRow;
    for (let ix=0; ix < this.routeStore.routes.length; ix++) {
        oneRow = this.routeStore.routes[ix];
        if (oneRow.schoolyear == selectedSchoolyear) result = oneRow.routeList
    }
    return result;
}
</script>
```

I think there must be a considerably more efficient/direct way to do what I'm doing. Can anyone suggest how I could do what I'm doing more concisely without undermining the clarity very much? I had thought of doing the work in a Pinia getter but I couldn't figure out how to pass it the school year from the form so that it could find the right routeList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the route list depends on the selected year. Typically, when a value is calculated according to a reactive dependency, you use [computed properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html). The advantage over a function is that computed properties will only be recalculated when the dependency changes, where a function has to be evaluated every time the component is updated.

See the snippet for an example:

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const { createPinia, defineStore } = Pinia;

const vuetify = createVuetify()
const pinia = createPinia()

const useRouteStore = defineStore('routeStore', {
    state: () => ({
        routes: [
            {schoolyear: "2022-2023", routeList: ["L-K311", "L-K312", "L-K325", "L-K326", "L-K336"]},
            {schoolyear: "2023-2024", routeList: ["C-K311", "C-K312", "C-K325", "C-K326", "C-K336"]},
            {schoolyear: "2024-2025", routeList: ["N-K311", "N-K312", "N-K325", "N-K326", "N-K336"]},
        ]
    })
})


const app = {
  template: `
      <v-app>
        <v-main>
          <v-select
            label="Schoolyear"
            :items="schoolYears" 
            v-model="selectedSchoolYear"
            @update:modelValue="selectedRoute = null"
          />
          <v-select
            label="Route"
            v-model="selectedRoute"
            :disabled="routesInSelectedYear.length === 0"
            :items="routesInSelectedYear"
          />
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
  `,
  setup(){
    const routeStore = useRouteStore()
    const schoolYears = computed(() => routeStore.routes.map(r => r.schoolyear))
    const selectedSchoolYear = ref(schoolYears.value[0])
    const routesInSelectedYear = computed(() => routeStore.routes.find(route => route.schoolyear === selectedSchoolYear.value)?.routeList ?? [])
    const selectedRoute = ref()
    return {
      schoolYears, selectedSchoolYear, routesInSelectedYear, selectedRoute
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).use(pinia).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia"></script>
```

But it is even simpler in this case. Since v-select can work with objects, there is no need to manually extract a list at all. You can have users select the dataset directly when they select the year.

See the updated snippet for an example:

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const { createPinia, defineStore, storeToRefs } = Pinia;

const vuetify = createVuetify()
const pinia = createPinia()

const useRouteStore = defineStore('routeStore', {
    state: () => ({
        routes: [
            {schoolyear: "2022-2023", routeList: ["L-K311", "L-K312", "L-K325", "L-K326", "L-K336"]},
            {schoolyear: "2023-2024", routeList: ["C-K311", "C-K312", "C-K325", "C-K326", "C-K336"]},
            {schoolyear: "2024-2025", routeList: ["N-K311", "N-K312", "N-K325", "N-K326", "N-K336"]},
        ]
    })
})


const app = {
  template: `
      <v-app>
        <v-main>
          <v-select
            label="Schoolyear"
            v-model="selectedRouteData"
            :items="routeData"
            item-title="schoolyear"
            item-value="schoolyear"
            return-object
            @update:modelValue="selectedRoute = null"
          />
          <v-select
            label="Route"
            v-model="selectedRoute"
            :items="selectedRouteData.routeList"
            :disabled="!selectedRouteData"
          />
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
  `,
  setup(){
    const routeStore = useRouteStore()
    const {routes: routeData} = storeToRefs(routeStore)
    const selectedRouteData = ref(routeStore.routes[0])
    const selectedRoute = ref()
    
    return {routeData, selectedRouteData, selectedRoute}
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).use(pinia).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pinia"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you spent on this very helpful answer!